# Xero API - PHP: session_handle error

Tags: php, api, xero-api

I have downloaded the source code from github. [XeroAPI](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroOAuth-PHP)
Is there anyone who solved the problem

> "Undefined index: session_handle in testRunner.php"?

I already looked in the Xero Community but it says that they've updated the code. But the latest code is still giving me a `session_handle error`. Thank you!